# Is it possible to use or pass AudioUnit data to AudioQueue for metering purposes

Tags: objective-c, ios7, audiotoolbox, audio-player

I have the following issue, I have multi channel mixer (not my implementation) using AudioToolbox Framework. I want master volume value on the output after the mix of all channels.

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I'm trying to use AudioQueueLevelMeterState for returning current volume level in range of 0 to 1. How can I pass the AUGraph or AudioUnit to audioQueue ? Maybe it's a little unclear question but still ...

```
-(float)volumeLevel
{
    UInt32 trueValue = true;
    AudioQueueSetProperty(audioQueue,kAudioQueueProperty_EnableLevelMetering,&trueValue,sizeof (UInt32));

    UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(AudioQueueLevelMeterState) * _streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    AudioQueueLevelMeterState *level = (AudioQueueLevelMeterState *)malloc(dataSize);

    float channelAvg = 0;

    OSStatus rc = AudioQueueGetProperty(audioQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter, level, &dataSize);
    if (rc) {
        NSLog(@"AudioQueueGetProperty(CurrentLevelMeter) returned %d", (int)rc);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < _streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame; i++) {
            channelAvg += level[i].mPeakPower;
        }
    }
    free(level);

    printf("Current peak :%f", channelAvg);
    return channelAvg;
}
```

Here is the actual snipped of the Mixer implementation:

```
typedef struct {
    UInt32               totalFrames;
    UInt32               nextFrame;
    UInt32               playedFrames;
    UInt32               playedLoops;
    UInt32               activeLoops;
    Float32              volume;
    AudioUnitSampleType  *dataLeft;
    AudioUnitSampleType  *dataRight;
} AudioMixerChannel, *AudioMixerChannelPointer;

static OSStatus inputRenderCallback(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList *ioData);

void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID, UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue);

void checkError(OSStatus error, const char *operation);


@interface AudioMixer ()
{
    AudioStreamBasicDescription _streamFormat;

    AUGraph _graph;

    AUNode _iONode;
    AUNode _mixerNode;

    AudioUnit _mixerUnit;

    AudioMixerChannel _channels[TRACK_MAX_CHANNELS];
}

@end

@implementation AudioMixer

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        size_t bytesPerSample = sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType);

        _streamFormat.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        _streamFormat.mFormatFlags       = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical;
        _streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket    = (int)bytesPerSample;
        _streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
        _streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame     = (int)bytesPerSample;
        _streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame  = 2;
        _streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel    = 8 * (int)bytesPerSample;
        _streamFormat.mSampleRate        = 44100.0;


        checkError(NewAUGraph(&_graph), "NewAUGraph");
        checkError(AUGraphOpen(_graph), "AUGraphOpen");
        checkError(AUGraphInitialize(_graph), "AUGraphInitialize");

        AudioComponentDescription iOUnitDescription;

        iOUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Output;
        iOUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
        iOUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
        iOUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
        iOUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;

        checkError(AUGraphAddNode(_graph, &iOUnitDescription, &_iONode), "AUGraphNewNode failed for I/O unit");

        AudioComponentDescription MixerUnitDescription;

        MixerUnitDescription.componentType          = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
        MixerUnitDescription.componentSubType       = kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer;
        MixerUnitDescription.componentManufacturer  = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
        MixerUnitDescription.componentFlags         = 0;
        MixerUnitDescription.componentFlagsMask     = 0;

        checkError(AUGraphAddNode(_graph, &MixerUnitDescription, &_mixerNode), "AUGraphNewNode failed for Mixer unit");
        checkError(AUGraphNodeInfo(_graph, _mixerNode, NULL, &_mixerUnit), "AUGraphNodeInfo - mixer unit");

        checkError(AUGraphConnectNodeInput(_graph, _mixerNode, 0, _iONode, 0), "AUGraphConnectNodeInput");

        for(int i=0; i<TRACK_MAX_CHANNELS; i++) {
            AURenderCallbackStruct inputCallbackStruct;

            inputCallbackStruct.inputProc        = &inputRenderCallback;
            inputCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon  = _channels;

            checkError(AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback(_graph, _mixerNode, i, &inputCallbackStruct), "AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback");
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution

First need to allow metering for mixer channels :

```
UInt32 allowMetering = 1;
    OSStatus status = AudioUnitSetProperty(_mixerUnit,
                                           kAudioUnitProperty_MeteringMode,
                                           kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                           0,
                                           &allowMetering,
                                           sizeof(allowMetering));

    if (status) { printf("AudioUnitGetParameter kMultiChannelMixerParam_PostAveragePower Input result %ld %08X %4.4s\n", (long)allowMetering, (unsigned int)allowMetering, (char*)&allowMetering); }
```

Metering is enabled, so I need to take the output volume in dB scale :

```
Float32 value = -120.0;

OSStatus result = AudioUnitGetParameter(_mixerUnit,
                                        kMultiChannelMixerParam_PostAveragePower,
                                        kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                        0,
                                        &value);

if (result) { printf("AudioUnitGetParameter kMultiChannelMixerParam_PostAveragePower Input result %ld %08X %4.4s\n", (long)result, (unsigned int)result, (char*)&result); }
```

Then you can use NSTimer to trigger refresh of the volume value.